# Conditional formatting with multiple cells in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on a spread sheet where I have a date in cell a4 and a drop down list in g4. I would like to do conditional formatting where the date in a4 reaches 6 months or older, it turns color based on g4 cell says "B-List", and stays that color until the date is less than 6 months. G4 will only have " A- List" or "B-List", and the format will only apply to "B-List" and a date that is 6 months or greater than today's date. I would like to put the conditional format in a4 if possible Thanks in advance Kevin.

Comment: Once you said older than 6 month, another said 6 month greater. Which one correct?

Comment: It is 6 months and greater. I need it to stay that color until the date is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula in conditional formatting.

```
=AND((TODAY()-A4)>=60,G4="B-List")
```

[image]